# Why won't Eclipse/adb detect my Samsung Galaxy Tab device on my Mac?

Tags: android, macos

I've connected my Samsung Galaxy Tab device to my Mac.  Yes, I've turned on debugging.  When I go to run my application to test on the device the device is not listed on the Android Device Chooser menu.  Running the ./adb devices shows no results.

NOTE: Posting this question for others to find.  When looking for the solution earlier all I was able to locate were answers to broken links to device driver downloads for Windows.

Comment: I had a hard time getting my Galaxy S to sync to my PC as well. I think Samsung just hates devs. Regardless, here's a link to drivers if you haven't already installed them. http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/wi-fi-tabs/GT-P7510MAVXAB

Comment: I've had the same problem, and none of the solutions here helped. My Mac detects the Samsung when it connects; I even get a message about a new network device. But "adb devices" shows nothing. Is there perhaps a file under /etc/ or something?

Comment: just happened to me. while i was seeking for solution, i realized that i was using a 3rd party usb extension cable. although the device is recognized and got notification saying "connected as media device", adb did not recognize it. worked after i removed extension cable on mac.

as for windows, still -not- recognized after downloading bunch of drivers from samsung and google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you uncheck

- Settings > Applications > Unknown Sources (Allow installation of non-Market applications)

Comment: after accidentally restarting eclipse settings, eclipse didn't recognize my samsung galaxy sII. I set the debug mode to off, then on, and the next time I connected the device - eclipse recognized it.

Comment: Settings -> Security -> Unknown Sources

Answer (score 5):

Turn on USB Debugging inside Settings > Applications > Developers Settings

Comment: On Windows the reverse is true.  You can't install the drivers while USB Debugging mode is on.  Turn it off, install drivers, then turn it back on.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to connect to a Mac, I had this issue with a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 4.3. To enable developer options, open the Settings app, tap on "About device" under the "General" tab and then tap on the "Build number" repeatedly (it's grayed out but you can tap on it anyway). A small pop-up will appear showing the amount of additional taps you need to do to turn on these options.

Once enabled, just turn on USB Debugging and it'll show up in Eclipse just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on my Mac and after 30 minutes tried switching USB ports and it finally started working on the second port.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by reboot the device (Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0)

Answer (score 2):

Update your driver for samsung. It can be found here: http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Connecting your phone after development mode is on, and USB debugging is on.
At connecting to the PC the phone asks to trust this location. Finally.

This fixed my problem while all other tips were incomplete.

Comment: Your solution is only applicable to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It does not answer your question of how to get ADB to see the device - I could not get that working.  But what I did to install an APK I needed to test was to put it in Dropbox on my computer, then install it from there on the device.

Comment: Look, it's pathetic I know.  I just needed to get it working, if I used ADB more than once a decade I would have put more effort into figuring out the real solution.  But I just needed to install an APK for testing

Comment: Actually, sarcasm isn't in my personality. Your ingenuity reminds me of me. Use your tools! Though sometimes, I think the difficulty in any field is a push to study enlightenment. "I can't take a simple step, something is wrong here, maybe world isn't as real as I thought" You always have 2 choices, push forward or give up, and within those two choices are two attitudes, positive and negative. Material happy, material sad, immaterial happy, homeless.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your device via USB hub instead of directly connecting to one of the usb ports on MAC. It worked that way for me. Please give a try.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a pop-up that comes up at times requesting the currently connected computer to have access to your device(not to be confused with the Linux not supported pop-up; it lies ; ] ). I continued to receive Target:Unknown in Eclipse until I managed to catch it and accept. This is on a Samsung Note 8", which I believe is registered as a Tab 10.1 in my Arch Linux udev rules.

Answer (score 1):

It may also happen that USB debugging is not checked on your device. Please go to developper options in your device and check it is enabled.

By the way, for devices with android Jelly Beam (4.2) and later versions, you will find out that this option is hidden. To activate it, click 7 times on the compilation number, and the option will be activated.

Answer (score 1):

Tried everything, nothing helped. Including

- USB debugging enabled
- MTP/PTP
- ADB restarted
- Device/PC restarted
- Tried Samsung's USB driver
- By tricking/modifying driver installer, installed Google OEM Usb drivers for Galaxy Tab.
- All software up-to-date

The only thing that helped is installing **Kies3 + setting PTP on device**, instantly authorization pops out in device. Everything OK now.

Kies3 download here: http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/

Comment: so this is the solution? Downloading KIES now

Answer (score 1):

Enable USB Debugging mode solve the problem!

For those who don't know how to enable it (it's very hidden on Android 4.3 onward), see [this](http://helpdesk.rsupport.com/entries/70478240-How-to-enable-developer-option-and-usb-debugging-).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this solved the problem: 
unchecked the Settings->Security->Unknown Sources,
clicked on the upper left corner and changed USB mode from MTP to PTP,
unplugged/plugged the device, and 
clicked OK on the USB debugging prompt.

Answer (score -3):

Had this problem last year, never solved it. Again, after googling high and low, I could not find a cure for the USB debugging flakiness. Now for the good news:

1) Root your device. 2) Install adbWireless widget from Play (I am in no way associated with the author).

You are now good to go. After starting adbWireless and following its directions, you can now debug through adb wirelessly to your device, in my case, the original 7" Galaxy Tab.