# Android device is not recognized in adb

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, samsung-mobile

I'm having a huge problem with my android samsung galaxy tab 7".

Whenever I try to connect it to my computer, instead of showing normally in my adb devices, the name of the device is : ????? and it status is online or device.

I really don't know what is the problem, any help would be really appreciated. If you need more info, I would be happy to give it.

Ubuntu : 11.04

Device : Samsung galaxy tab 7"

Android version : 3.2 HoneyComb

I also added the rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134953/why-wont-eclipse-adb-detect-my-samsung-galaxy-tab-device-on-my-mac

Comment: nope, the answer is not working for me...

Comment: See also http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1428610. After you do that, force a restart of the adb service with `adb kill-server`, then `adb devices` to restart it and list the devices. I had to manually kill adb sometimes after I make configuration changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this happens to me, I have to restart adb as follows:

$ adb kill-server
$ sudo /path_to_android_sdks/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb devices

I have this as a short script which I execute whenever I get the "?????" device showing up.  Works every time for me.

Answer (score 5):

There might be a problem with your USB device vender id.

Try different device ids as available in Android documentation (http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). Many devices are recognized using Google (18d1). All other things are simple. Just Create a file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

and add:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

then run:

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Then plug your device into PC with USB debugging OFF, after connecting, turn USB debugging ON and goto:

```
cd <sdk_path>/platform-tools
```

and run:

```
./adb devices
```

You'll see a device with some code excluding emulator (if running). That's it! Now you can  test your apps in your real device. While running, SDK will offer you to choose device if simulator is also running.

Answer (score 1):

Ghazi's response was useful but I had to do it in a different way on my Ubuntu 12.04. I had to change GROUP to OWNER="your username on ubuntu" and then it worked.