# Samsung S2, Android on MacOSX

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adb

This has been asked a lot. I can't get my device running with ADB on MacOSX. I know this is a software problem, because I can connect via the Samsung application Kies.

see

1) [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)

2) [Android device is not recognized in adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790139/android-device-is-not-recognized-in-adb)

3) [Why won't Eclipse/adb detect my Samsung Galaxy Tab device on my Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134953/why-wont-eclipse-adb-detect-my-samsung-galaxy-tab-device-on-my-mac)

Possible solutions of which none worked for me.

1. start-server , kill-server
2. USB-Debugging on?
3. Add vendor ID to  ./android/adb_usb.ini
4. usb cable defect?
5. add sdk path
6. sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext (?)
7. Connect your device via USB hub instead of directly connecting to one of the usb ports on MAC.

details

OSX 10.8.0, 
Eclipse Juno (4.2.1), 
Android 4.0.3, 
apropriate SDK #15

Edit: Tried on Windows 7 also. Update firmware. Nothing working.

Comment: First question, what versions of Eclipse, OSX? I use a Mac everyday to develop for Android without any issues on my S2 or any other phone. You should not need to edit files or plays with kexts.

Comment: OSX 10.8, Eclipse SDK Version: 4.2.1, Build id: M20120914-1800

Comment: 10.8 as opposed to 10.8.2? Eclipse Helios, Indigo, or Juno? The ADT plugin is 20.0.3, what does 4.2.1 refer to?

Comment: If you have Android file transfer installed, uninstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I got it. I thought I was in debugging mode, because Android has this weird greyed out checkbox. I could activate USB testing mode, and now it is working.